# new to programming had a question about netlogo

Tags: netlogo

So I was wondering how I could increase the speed and size of my fish whenever they gain +1 energy

this is what I have so far

```
update-plots'

  tick
  ask fishes[
    set Btimer (Btimer - 1)
    forward 1
    right random 80
    left random 80
    if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 0 = (green)[
      set Energy (Energy + 7)
      set pcolor blue
    
    set Energy (Energy - 1)
    if (Energy <= 0)[                                     
      die]
```

,,,

Answer (score 1):

The speed is your `forward 1` so you are going to have to link that to the energy. Something like `forward Energy / 7` instead of `forward 1` would work.

On the size, you can simply add a line within the code block where you increase the energy to also increase size. Since `size` is an automatic variable, something like `set size size + 0.3`